# changes in TvalueListeditor

Tags: delphi

I wonder what will be the best way to readout the changes made in a TValueListeditor.
The stringList i'm using has the following structure :

```
   aParam1=100

   aParam2=222

   aparam3=....
   ....
   ...
```

with one line of code I can assign this stringlist to the TValueListEditor

```
ValueListEditor.strings.assign(myDataStringlist);
```

and edit this stringlist.  How to save my changes now back to the Stringlist ?

Comment: Why do you need a string list at all? Isn't `ValueListEditor.Strings` enough?

Comment: @David because it is not wise to use visual controls as data containers? if you need the values in some places of your app you are not willing to ask a form control

Comment: @SirRufo That's true enough. However, for small simple apps people often don't bother to do it *right*. And certainly `TValueListEditor` doesn't make it easy to do it *right* by holding a copy of the data. To do it right you'd want a component that displayed a view of data that was held elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call   `myDataStringlist.Assign(ValueListEditor1.strings);`

both are TStrings

TStringList = class(TStrings)

TValueListEditor

property Strings: TStrings read GetStrings write SetStrings;

Comment: should I do that in the ValueListEditor.onchange event  or any other location?

Comment: As far I don't know what for you'll need it, I only can describe when I would do it. Usually when user decided input is complete e.g. by clicking a button.